# copy files across directories using terminal in mac

Tags: macos, shell

How to copy all files with an specific extension `.SAV` from one directory (including all subdirectories within that directory) to another one? I am using the terminal from mac. I have tried

```
    /Users/tournillon/my_directory/research_projects/dissertation_related/inequality
    Antonio-P-Tournillon-Ramoss-iMac:inequality tournillon$ ls
    Brazil              dhs_dados           imr201101app.pdf
    GHME_Education_final.pptx   dhs_sav_files
    Antonio-P-Tournillon-Ramoss-iMac:inequality tournillon$ dhs_dados /*.SAV/ dhs_sav_files/
```

I would assume this is a trivial task but I just can't get the syntax right.

Many thanks,

Antonio Pedro.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`find /source/directory -iname \*.sav -exec cp {} /destination/directory/ \;`

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a UNIX copy,

```
cp -R <dirA>/*.sav <dirB>/
```

I'm not sure what dhs_dados is in your question..

Comment: will this command recurse into sub directories of the source directory?

Comment: `dhs_dados` is the directory which I am copy from. This works fine except that it also copy the all subdirectories, with all files within it, and thus not only the `.SAV` files.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use cp *.SAV directory

Comment: That would not find the files in subdirectories.